# How to initialize class members in singleton pattern?

Tags: c++, singleton

I've a class following singleton approach, but where do i initialize class members if its constructor is private?

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass() {};                //constructor is private         
    MyClass(const MyClass&);            
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&);
public:
    static MyClass& Instance()
    {
        static MyClass singleton;
        return singleton;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why is there a problem, doing it in the constructor ? Instance is a member of the class and should have no issue calling the constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can initialize the class members in the constructor itself *as usual*, even be it private.

The constructor is *private* to the outside world, **not** to the static member function `Instance()`. That means, the line `static MyClass singleton` in `Instance()` actually invokes default constructor, and that is valid, as `Instance()` has access to `private` members of the class!

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor, that's what it's there for. It has full access to members.

Also, be aware that this is unsafe in a multi-threaded application.

Comment: unsafe is highly dependent on system.

Answer (score 0):

Your Instance method calls the constructor. The Instance method is static so you can access it without it being already built and since it is a member, it can call a private constructor.

Your constructor can then do any necessary initialization.

As an aside, your singleton member should be a pointer.

Comment: I don't think it matters if the member is a pointer if it's a static inside a method. Even if it's a static member of the class that should be OK (although you lose a chance at lazy initialization) unless I am missing something.

Comment: That particular style is called Meyer's Singleton and it was introduced in 'More Effective C++' (Item 26).